Recover OAUTHBEARER Token from Kafka
I need to get token that strimzi-oauth-lib is getting from my oracle access manager. This library provides a JaasClientOauthLoginCallbackHandler and kafka take care of make an callback and gets token by its own. I was wondering if is possible to recover this token and reuse it on my microservice.
I'm tryied to load this lib instances on classloader, but I was unable to get the values loaded in this instances. Since it's not build on top of spring, it's impossible to load it from spring's context. I'm trying to figure out if sspring-kafka provides it on its beans.
